# How do I import only the class(es) of a component?

Tags: material-ui

I would like to import a MaterialUI class, without importing the component itself.
Precisely, I'd need the `MuiInputBase-root` styles. But the class is only defined if `InputBase` is imported, so solely doing `className="MuiInputBase-root"` does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, 
I think you could just either use the input base as standalone import (https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/ ) or just copy that few line of css from the original styles if you never intend to use anything from the entire package.

Comment: That's what I tried, importing the `styles` from the source code. But these are the default styles, while I need the computed ones, with my theme applied to them...

Answer (score 0):

You can import the component class like this

```
import inputBaseClasses from '@mui/material';

// Reference the class in Styled Components:
[`& .${inputBaseClasses.root}`]: {
    color: 'black',
}
```

https://mui.com/base/getting-started/customization/#applying-custom-css-rules